# How to benchmark mysql join query of 5 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have table A with tables B, C, D, E all of which belong to A.

I want to compile a report so that columns of all tables are all in one row, so yea a join.  So the query would be:

```
select A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*, E.*
from A
left join B on B.a_id = A.id
left join C on C.a_id = A.id
-- etc.
```

This will return lots of rows.  How to benchmark this? Get a timed result for joining tables of X rows?  It's a one to one relation between them, ie A - B, A- C, etc.

Comment: Just try running `EXPLAIN` on your query.  The report should hopefully give you some insight as to what is going on.

Comment: My earlier question?